# How to group an array with its object key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array which contains employee details and salary information. I want to group employees salary details with employee id.

This is the input array:

```js
let employeeDetails = [{
  "employeeDetail": {
    "empID": "XXYYZZ11",
    "firstname": "abc",
    "joinedAt": "13/04/2014",
    "address": "VVGGHHNN"
  },
  "employeeSalaryDetails": [{
    "month": "Jan",
    "salaryAmount": "35000",
    "Bank": "XXXXX",
    "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"
  }]
}, {
  "employeeDetails": [{
    "empID": "XXYYZZ11",
    "firstname": "abc",
    "joinedAt": "13/04/2014",
    "address": "VVGGHHNN"
  }],
  "employeeSalaryDetails": [{
    "month": "Feb",
    "salaryAmount": "35000",
    "Bank": "XXXXX",
    "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"
  }]
}]
```

This is the output I would like to achieve:

```js
let employeeDetails = [{
  "employeeDetails": [{
    "empID": "XXYYZZ11",
    "firstname": "abc",
    "joinedAt": "13/04/2014",
    "address": "VVGGHHNN"
  }],
  "employeeSalaryDetails": [{
    "month": "Jan",
    "salaryAmount": "35000",
    "Bank": "XXXXX",
    "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"
  }, {
    "month": "Feb",
    "salaryAmount": "35000",
    "Bank": "XXXXX",
    "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"
  }]
}]
```

This is what I tried, but it didn't get the result I want.

```js
function employeeGroup(empArray, key) {
  return empArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
    (obj[item[key]] = obj[item[key]] || []).push(item)
    return obj
  }, {})
}

employeeGroup(employeeDetails, "empId")
```

I am new to Javascript. Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: What does your employeeGroup function return ?

Comment: can `employeeDetails` have more than one object? what about `employeeSalaryDetails`? what if you have more data?

Comment: This is indeed a strange structure to begin with. Why is `employeeDetails` an array?? Imagine it has 2 entries, and the second entry has a different `empID` value...

Comment: @AliceOualouest its already there in question

Comment: @NinaScholz yes employeeDetails has more than one object.

Comment: @trincot kindly check the empId , both are same only

Comment: @mageshtech, I think you miss my point. I talk about the `employeeDetails` array. In your input it *always* only has one object entry. What if you would have more than one object on *one* array? What would guarantee that multiple entries would not have conflicting information? And so, why oh why is `employeeDetails` an array and not directly an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using destructuring to extract the first array element as item, and employeeSalaryDetails property.
Your object with empID is wrapped inside the array.  You weren't pushing the meployeeSalaryDetails object.  Also your empId should be empID.

```js
function employeeGroup(empArray, key) {
  return Object.values(empArray.reduce(
  (obj,{employeeDetails: [item], employeeSalaryDetails}) => {
      (obj[item[key]] = obj[item[key]] ||
       { employeeDetails: item, employeeSalaryDetails:[] })
           .employeeSalaryDetails.push(...employeeSalaryDetails)
      return obj
  }, {}))
}
console.log(
  employeeGroup(employeeDetails, "empID")
)
```

```html
<script>
  let employeeDetails = [{
    "employeeDetails": [{
      "empID": "XXYYZZ11",
      "firstname": "abc",
      "joinedAt": "13/04/2014",
      "address": "VVGGHHNN"
    }],
    "employeeSalaryDetails": [{
      "month": "Jan",
      "salaryAmount": "35000",
      "Bank": "XXXXX",
      "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"
    }]
  }, {
    "employeeDetails": [{
      "empID": "XXYYZZ11",
      "firstname": "abc",
      "joinedAt": "13/04/2014",
      "address": "VVGGHHNN"
    }],
    "employeeSalaryDetails": [{
      "month": "Feb",
      "salaryAmount": "35000",
      "Bank": "XXXXX",
      "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ"
    }]
  }]
</script>
```

Comment: you are near to the answer , but i don't want key like this  `{
  "XXYYZZ11": {
    "employeeDetails": {`

Comment: Oh, wrap it in Object.values to unwrap the values

Comment: Check to make sure this is actually what you want btw.  The structure is a little odd.  Make sure you check what the other people are saying about the data structure, to decide if this is really the kind of structure you want.  I've seen structures like this before, where duplicated keys and values are more convenient to process on the backend and DB especially with legacy stuff, but it's usually not the best choice.

Comment: @user12042 `(obj,{employeeDetails: [item], employeeSalaryDetails}) => { ` how to make employeedDetails as dynamic one

Comment: you'll have to explain what you mean by dynamic one.  do you want to search the entire details?  or is the key going to change names?  and how is it that that will happen?

Comment: @user12042 actually key name is changing dynamically ,in my array employeeDetails will be details some time .At the time i have `{employeeDetails: [item]` should be `details:[item]`

Comment: do you only need to choose between employeeDetails or details, or do you have a range of keys to look for?  do you need to check for ids that overlap in both details and employeeDetails?  is the final key supposed to be employeeDetails or details? 
 destructuring is not really good for extracting a dynamic list of keys, since it was designed to just be syntax sugar that is directly translatable to property access.

Comment: try creating a new question asking about how to extract key names that might change.  make sure to answer the questions I asked here, as well as giving demo input/output data.  mention if you want it coded "elegantly" or "high performance" (include the type of large data set you need it for if asking for performance).  You can use the code I've posted in this answer, to create a snippet in your question, that people answering your question can use to run the code.  If you write the question well, it might even net you some upvote points.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce` and to filter out the duplicate employee records you can make use of `filter` and `some`. Here is a working example.

```js
var employeeDetails = [{ "employeeDetails": [ { "empID":"XXYYZZ11", "firstname": "abc", "joinedAt": "13/04/2014", "address": "VVGGHHNN" } ], "employeeSalaryDetails": [ { "month": "Jan", "salaryAmount": "35000", "Bank": "XXXXX", "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ" } ]}, { "employeeDetails": [ { "empID": "XXYYZZ11", "firstname": "abc", "joinedAt": "13/04/2014", "address": "VVGGHHNN" } ], "employeeSalaryDetails": [ { "month": "Feb", "salaryAmount": "35000", "Bank": "XXXXX", "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ" } ] }];

var result = [employeeDetails.reduce((acc, {employeeDetails, employeeSalaryDetails})=>{
    acc['employeeDetails'] = acc['employeeDetails'] || [];
    employeeDetails = employeeDetails.filter(k=>!acc['employeeDetails'].some(l=>l.empID==k.empID));
    acc['employeeDetails'] = [...acc['employeeDetails'], ...employeeDetails];
    acc['employeeSalaryDetails'] = [...(acc['employeeSalaryDetails'] || []), ...employeeSalaryDetails];
    return acc;
},{})];

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Array will contain only one Object, the below code would work.

```
    let employeeDetails = [{ "employeeDetails": [{ "empID": "XXYYZZ11", "firstname": "abc", "joinedAt": "13/04/2014", "address": "VVGGHHNN" }], "employeeSalaryDetails": [{ "month": "Jan", "salaryAmount": "35000", "Bank": "XXXXX", "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ" }] }, { "employeeDetails": [{ "empID": "XXYYZZ11", "firstname": "abc", "joinedAt": "13/04/2014", "address": "VVGGHHNN" }], "employeeSalaryDetails": [{ "month": "Feb", "salaryAmount": "35000", "Bank": "XXXXX", "PfAccnum": "XXAAQQWWWWQ" }] }]
    function getEmployeeDetails(id){
        let employeeDetail = {employeeDetails:[],employeeSalaryDetails:[]};
        employeeDetails.forEach(function(eachDetail){
            let ed = eachDetail.employeeDetails[0];
            let es = eachDetail.employeeSalaryDetails[0];
            if(ed.empID == id){
                employeeDetail.employeeDetails = ed;
                employeeDetail.employeeSalaryDetails.push(es);
            }
        });
        return [employeeDetail];
    }
    console.log(getEmployeeDetails("XXYYZZ11"));
```

Comment: Array is not a static one , need for dynamic array , because in a organisation more than one employee will work right ?

Comment: I am not referring to the outer array. i am referring to the inner array ( employeeDetails. employeeDetails ). Please run and check the code. It works good for multiple employees.

Comment: its not working,if employeeDetails array has another entry like this ,also i need employeeDetail as object ,refer the expected output `{"employeeDetails": [{"empID": "XXYY22","firstname": "XYZ","joinedAt": "11/05/2016","address": "VVGGHHNN"}],"employeeSalaryDetails": [{"month": "Jan","salaryAmount": "25000","Bank": "XXXXX","PfAccnum": "SDSDSDSDSD"}]}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {item[]} arr 
 * @param {(item)=>item[<GroupField>]} g 
 * @returns 
 */
function groupBy ( arr, g ) {
    let len = arr.length
    for ( let i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        const a = arr.pop();
        const b = g( a );
        const c = arr.find( e => e.d == b )
        if ( c ) {
            c.e.push( a )
        } else {
            arr.unshift( ( {
                d: g( a ),
                e: [ a ]
            } ) )
        }
    }
    return arr.map( e => ( { [ e.d ]: e.e } ) ).reduce( ( p, c ) => ( { ...p, ...c } ) );
}


const result = groupBy( [
    { name: 'a', group: 1 },
    { name: "b", group: 1 },
    { name: "c", group: 10 }
], ( item ) => item.group );


console.log( result );
```